# Access/Get SQL Developer Table 'Details'

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a list of tables in an Oracle Schema. I use SQL Developer to build my queries. I can click on each table within the schema in SQL Developer and get access to a number of tabs, one of which is 'Details':

[image]

Within the 'Details' window, I have a property called 'Comments' which contains a description of what the table is for.

[image]

Now, I have quite a few tables and I want to somehow grab the table name and description in that comments property for each table and put it into a spreadsheet. Is there any way to do that in SQL Developer? Maybe a query? Or some built in function that iterates over each table and provides that information? I thought about using python, but I'm not sure I can access the 'Details' of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Every once in a while, I find a solution before i have some of you awesome people answer for me, so i thought I'd post up what I found. This is the query I found that works:

> select * from all_tab_comments where owner = 'your_schema_name_here'

This provides a list of all the tables in the schema (owner) I want and provides the comments I was looking for. From there, I can just export to an excel spreadsheet.